# Listar todas as Roles em CheckBox e marcar as roles que o Usuário Possui

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou criando um Sistema de Gerenciamento de Usuários em Asp.net MVC 4 com duas Tabelas Simples.

Usuários e Roles.

Consigo criar os usuários normalmente selecionando as Roles que ele vai possuir.

Na hora de Editar estou tentando Listar todas as Roles em CheckBox e Marcar Apenas as roles que o usuário possui, sendo assim possível alterar as roles do usuário na edição.

Segue abaixo como estou tentando fazer.

## Controller

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    var usuario = _ctx.Usuarios.Include("Roles").ToList();
    var user = usuario.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UsuarioId == id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.Praca = new SelectList(_ctx.Pracas.ToList(), "PracaId", "Nome");
    ViewBag.Roles = _p.GetAllRoles();

    return View(user);
}
```

## View Edit

```html
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <h4>Permissões</h4>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
    {
        foreach (var roles in Model.Roles)
        {
           <label style="display: block">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="@item.Equals(roles.Nome)" /> @item
           </label>
        }
     }
</div>
```

Dessa maneira os dados estão vindo duplicados.

Ex: Digamos que exista duas Roles "Admin" e "Gerente" e o Usuário possui as Duas, a saída fica:

```
[x] Admin
[ ] Admin
[ ] Gerente
[x] Gerente
```

Se o Usuário tiver apenas uma das Roles a Saída sai do jeito que quero que fique.

```
[x] Admin
[ ] Gerente
```

Comment: Tenho o mesmo problema pendente para resolver à umas semanas, tive de pegar noutras prioridades do projecto e nunca mais corrigi esta situação!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, sua lógica não está muito boa, pois você está usando dois `foreach` aninhados, imprimindo coisas na página... isso seria a lógica de uma tabela, mas não de uma lista.

A lógica correta para uma lista, é fazer a impressão do `input` dentro do primeiro `foreach`, que é o que itera sobre todas as opções de input que podem haver... pelo que eu entendi `ViewBag.Roles` contém todas as opções de roles.

Além disso, colocar `checked="true"` ou `checked="false"` no seu HTML vai dar no mesmo... ambos os checkboxes vão ser selecionados. Para não selecionar, o atributo `checked` deve ser removido por inteiro.

Faça assim que deve funcionar:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <h4>Permissões</h4>

    @foreach (var role in ViewBag.Roles)
    {
        bool estaSelecionado = false;
        foreach (var roleUsuario in Model.Roles)
        {
            if (roleUsuario.Nome == role)
            {
                estaSelecionado = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        <label style="display: block">
            @if (estaSelecionado)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> @role
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="checkbox" /> @role
            }
        </label>
     }
</div>
```

Agora para simplificar, você pode usar LINQ to objects e escrever tudo em poucas linhas.

**EDIT**

Já que a simplicidade está sendo questionada você pode usar o código abaixo, que está mais símples, usa LINQ, e possui markup semanticamente correto.

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <h4>Permissões</h4>

    @foreach (var role in ViewBag.Roles)
    {
        var roleId = "role-" + role.Replace(" ", "-");
        <div>
            @Html.CheckBox("role",
                    Model.Roles.Any(r => r.Nome == role),
                    new { value = role, id = roleId })
            <label for="@roleId">@role</label>
        </div>
     }
</div>
```

Gostaria de salientar que a tag `label` está sendo usada de forma errada no seu código, está faltando o atributo `for`... da forma que mencionei no exemplo anterior.

Também notei que você não postou sua action de POST para receber os dados após a edição... por isso coloquei todos os checkboxes com mesmo nome, assim você poderia fazer uma action assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0, string[] role)
{
    // role contém uma lista dos roles selecionados, mas não contém os não selecionados
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Miguel, realmente minha lógica estava totalmente errada, obrigado pela força.

Comment: @HermesAutran você marcou essa opção como resposta e de fato funciona e está ok. Mas eu recomendo você dar uma olhada na resposta que postei mais abaixo onde o código está mais simples e semântico.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo o fato de ter editado a sua versão e colocado em negrito o texto "já que a simplicidade está sendo questionada" parece ter soado com alguma soberba, com certa falta de fair play. Me desculpe se eu estiver enganado. Não tenho objetivo algum de lhe causar desconforto ou ofensa. A resposta já foi aceita, se você viu algum problema na minha tentativa de oferecer outra opinião posso retirar o comentário e a resposta sem problemas. Abraços.

Comment: @iuristona Não vi problema algum. Como o comentário foi diretamente na minha resposta, eu entendi como sendo um convite a melhorá-la. E o negrito... pô, ficou estranho mesmo. Foi uma forma de fazer referência à causa da edição... mas parece provocação mesmo. hehe =) Por favor, não remova nada.

Comment: Tirei o negrito, de forma que não pareça o que não é.

Comment: iuristona e MiguelAngelo As duas formas funcionaram e realmente resolveram o meu problema. Estou estudando a forma dada pelo Cigano sobre MemberShipProvider e tentar usar os métodos nativos das classes, aprendi bastante com as soluções dadas. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando as respostas: no MVC4 há duas classes e um atributo que implementam autenticação, sistema de usuários e roles. São elas:

- `MembershipProvider`
- `RoleProvider`
- `AuthorizeAttribute`

Basta derivar cada um e escrever os `override`s. Com isso, você poderá usar os métodos nativos do Framework, por exemplo:

- `User.IsInRole("MinhaRole")`;
- `Roles.CreateRole("MinhaRole")`;

Ou então decorar suas Actions com o atributo `[Authorize]`.

Você pode criar telas de cadastro e basear suas implementações em outros models.

Exemplos:

**Web.config da Raiz**

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="TesteMaroto.Infrastructure.MyRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="TesteMaroto.Infrastructure.MyMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <machineKey validationKey="2183859A758E675951A39436AFD2FE57ABF398DA3627AE39B76075C995CF0094488F816CA5E6DA572627612C14F934589FF5B0CA92CC55F51F9099B10EB3F6F1" decryptionKey="8A46124FEC091DE2C82EDF529F884CC24CC8F38D6839A9FA6F86279DE5654261" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
  </system.web>
```

> **Atenção**: Gere sua `<machineKey>` aqui: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

**MembershipProvider**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace TesteMaroto.Infrastructure
{
    public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente aqui seu procedimento de alteração de senha.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do Usuário</param>
        /// <param name="oldPassword">Senha antiga</param>
        /// <param name="newPassword">Nova senha</param>
        /// <returns>True se a operação foi feita com sucesso; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método se você quiser criar um esquema de recuperação de senha por pergunta e resposta.
        /// Este método altera a pergunta e a resposta.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do Usuário</param>
        /// <param name="password">Senha</param>
        /// <param name="newPasswordQuestion">Nova pergunta para recuperação da senha</param>
        /// <param name="newPasswordAnswer">Nova resposta para recuperação da senha</param>
        /// <returns>True se a operação foi feita com sucesso; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método um usuário e retorna um objeto do tipo MembershipUser preenchido.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do Usuário</param>
        /// <param name="password">Senha</param>
        /// <param name="email">E-Mail</param>
        /// <param name="passwordQuestion">Pergunta para recuperação de senha</param>
        /// <param name="passwordAnswer">Resposta para recuperação de senha</param>
        /// <param name="isApproved">É aprovado ou precisa de uma confirmação extra, como aquelas enviadas por e-mail</param>
        /// <param name="providerUserKey">O objeto que representa a chave primária do seu model de usuário. Pode ser int, Guid...</param>
        /// <param name="status">Um objeto do Status da Criação. É preenchido dentro deste método</param>
        /// <returns>Objeto do tipo MembershipUser</returns>
        public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para excluir um usuário.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Nome do usuário</param>
        /// <param name="deleteAllRelatedData">Indicativo para exclusão de todos os dados relacionados ao usuário.</param>
        /// <returns>True se a operação foi feita com sucesso; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework se você permite reiniciar a senha do usuário ou não.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool EnablePasswordReset
        {
            get { 
                // return true; ou então return false;
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework se você permite que a senha seja reenviada ao usuário caso ele assim solicite.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
        {
            get {
                // return true; ou então return false;
                throw new NotImplementedException(); 
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder retornar todos os usuários cadastrados por um determinado e-mail.
        /// MembershipUserCollection é uma lista especial.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="emailToMatch">Endereço de e-mail a ser localizado</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">Índice da página. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">Número de registros para uma página. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <param name="totalRecords">Total de registros encontrados. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <returns>Objeto do tipo MembershipUserCollection</returns>
        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder retornar todos os usuários cadastrados por um determinado nome.
        /// MembershipUserCollection é uma lista especial.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="usernameToMatch">Nome a ser localizado</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">Índice da página. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">Número de registros para uma página. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <param name="totalRecords">Total de registros encontrados. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <returns>Objeto do tipo MembershipUserCollection</returns>
        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder obter todos os usuários.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">Índice da página. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">Número de registros para uma página. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <param name="totalRecords">Total de registros encontrados. Serve para fazer paginação pra uma View, por exemplo</param>
        /// <returns>Objeto do tipo MembershipUserCollection</returns>
        public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder retornar o número de usuários online.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Número de usuários online.</returns>
        public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder retornar a senha de um usuário baseado na resposta fornecida em tela.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do usuário</param>
        /// <param name="answer">Resposta fornecida</param>
        /// <returns>Senha, se a resposta estiver correta.</returns>
        public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder retornar todos os dados sobre um usuário procurando pelo Login do usuário.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do usuário</param>
        /// <param name="userIsOnline">Indicativo de usuário online</param>
        /// <returns>Objeto do tipo MembershipUser</returns>
        public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder retornar todos os dados sobre um usuário procurando pela chave primária do Model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="providerUserKey">A chave do Model (pode ser int, Guid...)</param>
        /// <param name="userIsOnline">Indicativo de usuário online</param>
        /// <returns>Objeto do tipo MembershipUser</returns>
        public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework poder retornar o Login de um usuário procurando pelo e-mail do usuário.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="email">E-mail do usuário</param>
        /// <returns>Login do Usuário</returns>
        public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework quantas tentativas erradas de senha tem um usuário antes da sua conta ser bloqueada.
        /// </summary>
        public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework quantos caracteres não-alfanuméricos deve ter a senha do usuário.
        /// </summary>
        public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework a quantidade mínima de caracteres que deve ter a senha do usuário.
        /// </summary>
        public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework o tempo da janela de tentativas de senha do usuário (em minutos).
        /// </summary>
        public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework o formato da senha do usuário.
        /// </summary>
        public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework a expressão regular que avalia a força da senha do usuário.
        /// </summary>
        public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework se o registro do usuário requer pergunta e resposta para recuperação de senha.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework se o e-mail deve ser único no registro de usuário.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para indicar ao Framework como reiniciar e recuperar uma senha gerada pelo sistema para um usuário.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do usuário</param>
        /// <param name="answer">Resposta de senha.</param>
        /// <returns>Nova senha gerada, se a resposta estiver correta.</returns>
        public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework como desbloquear um usuário bloqueado no sistema.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">Login do usuário</param>
        /// <returns>True se a operação foi feita com sucesso; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework como atualizar os dados de um usuário.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user">Dados do usuário a ser atualizado.</param>
        public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente esta property para indicar ao Framework como validar um usuário para login.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do usuário</param>
        /// <param name="password">Senha do usuário</param>
        /// <returns>True se usuário acertou a senha e pode se considerar autenticado; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**RoleProvider**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace TesteMaroto.Infrastructure
{
    public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework adicionar usuários a roles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="usernames">Array de Logins.</param>
        /// <param name="roleNames">Roles às quais os usuários serão associados.</param>
        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework criar uma Role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="roleName">Nome da Role.</param>
        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework excluir uma Role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="roleName">Nome da Role</param>
        /// <param name="throwOnPopulatedRole">Indicativo se deve haver uma exceção caso a exclusão seja de uma Role que tem usuários associados a ela</param>
        /// <returns>True se a operação foi feita com sucesso; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework procurar se um usuário está associado a uma Role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="roleName">Nome da Role</param>
        /// <param name="usernameToMatch">Usuário para pesquisa</param>
        /// <returns>Lista de usuários encontrados</returns>
        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework retornar todas as Roles existentes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Array de Strings com o nome das Roles.</returns>
        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework retornar todas as Roles de um usuário.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do usuário</param>
        /// <returns>Array de Strings com o nome das roles.</returns>
        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework retornar todos os usuários de uma Role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="roleName">Nome da Role</param>
        /// <returns>Array de Strings com os Logins dos usuários.</returns>
        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework verificar se um usuário está em uma Role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Login do usuário</param>
        /// <param name="roleName">Nome da role</param>
        /// <returns>True se usuário está numa Role; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework remover usuários das Roles passadas como parâmetro.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="usernames">Logins dos usuários</param>
        /// <param name="roleNames">Nomes das Roles</param>
        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método para o Framework verificar se uma Role existe.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="roleName">Nome da Role</param>
        /// <returns>True se Role existe; False em caso contrário.</returns>
        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se puderes compartilhar algum exemplo ficarei muito grato!!

Comment: @HermesAutran Vou incrementando a resposta conforme for precisando. Continue acompanhando.

Comment: posso usar a classe com uma Classe de Usuário personalizada caso eu não queira as propriedades do usuário do MemberShipProvider?

Ex: Caso queira que o usuário tenha, "DataNascimento", "Cpf", "Cidade"...

Comment: @HermesAutran Aí você precisa derivar `MembershipUser`. No fim da tarde vou colocar mais exemplos.

Comment: Boa ideia usar Membership, mas todo ASP.NET está evoluindo para o uso do ASP.NET Identity. Essa opção de criar novos atributos que o @HermesAutran perguntou está simplificada lá. Sugiro pensar em estudar direto o ASP.NET Identity. Eu atualmente utilizo Membership e pretendo migrar minha aplicação.

Comment: @iuristona Não recomendo ainda, principalmente porque a documentação relacionada com o Identity ainda está incompleta. Abri algumas questões no SO gringo e ainda não tive resposta. Tive que voltar para o Membership.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez vc poderia colar aqui as questões? estou estudando o Identity e estou gostando, na versão 2.0 (beta2) tem algumas novidades boas, como poder escolher o tipo da PK que era apenas string, mas de fato conheço algumas restrições.

Comment: @iuristona http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785703/owin-customizing-usermanager e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817339/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-microsoft-web-helpers-preapplicationstar (a segunda é decorrente da atualização dos packages para as versões mais novas do Web Helpers).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez postei algo que talvez você possa checar, lá no SO.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13142/discussion-between-cigano-morrison-mendez-and-iuristona)

Answer (score 1):

Você tem as roles existentes no `ViewBag.Roles`, correto? Então seu foreach deveria ficar assim:

```
@foreach (var role in ViewBag.Roles)
{
    <label style="display: block">
         <input type="checkbox" "@(Model.Roles.Select(n => n.Nome).Contains(role) ? "checked=checked" : "")" /> @role
    </label>
 }
```

Onde `Model.Roles.Select(n => n.Nome).Contains(role) ? "checked" : ""` verifica se o `Model.Roles` contém aquela role da iteração e atribui `checked=checked` ao `checkbox`.

Comment: Eu testei o seu exemplo Iuri, porém me aparece o seguinte erro!

"A melhor correspondência de método sobrecarregado 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<App.Relatorio.Models.Role>.Contains(App.Relatorio.Models.Role)' tem alguns argumentos inválidos"

Comment: Sua resposta está boa cara... só falta um detalhe: na questão o Model.Roles é uma lista de objetos com a propriedade Nome, então uma forma de verificar seria usando LINQ: `Model.Roles.Any(r => r.Nome == role)` ao invés de usar Contains. =)

Comment: Eu estava assumindo que `ViewBag.Roles` era uma coleção de `Role`, vejo agora que  é uma coleção de `string`, eu modificaria de outra maneira: `Model.Roles.Select(n => n.Name).Contains(role)` puramente por considerar Contains mais semântico que Any nesse caso.

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade checked não é boleana, uma vez declarada ela seleciona sozinha.

Tente utilizar isso na View:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
<h4>Permissões</h4>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
{
    foreach (var roles in Model.Roles)
    {
       <label style="display: block">
            @if(item.Equals(roles.Nome))
            {
                 <input type="checkbox" checked /> @item
            }
            else
            {
                 <input type="checkbox"/> @item 
            }
       </label>
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ele vai duplicar o Checkbox do mesmo jeito, pois ele vai verificar com todas as outras roles e toda vez que item.Equals(roles.Nome) não for true ele vai imprimir o check desmarcado com o mesmo nome do @item que está sendo verificado! =/